# how to find parametrization for an intersection of a plane and one sheet hyperboloid

Tags: multivariable-calculus, parametrization

I need to find a parametrization for intersection of a plane and one sheet hyperboloid.

one sheet hyperboloid equation: $x^2+y^2-z^2=1$

plane equation: $x-1=0$

I don't know how to parametrize the intersection, but I do know that it is an "X" shape.

From the equations I get:

$x=1$

$y^2=z^2$

I tried many combinations like:

$r(t)=(x(t),y(t),z(t))=(1,|t|,t)$ or $(1,|t|,|t|)$

but no matter what I tried I'm not getting the wanted shape. I added a picture that shows the  intersection of the hyperboloid and the plane; it's the black "X".

[image: hyperboloid and the plane intersection]

Comment: A simple approach of substituting $x=1$ gives $y^2 - z^2 = 0$, so it is clear that there are two (intersecting, in this case) branches, $y = \pm z$.  So depending on how you intend to display the figure, you may need to use a pair of parameterizations, e.g. $(1,t,t)$ and $(1,t,-t)$.

Comment: is it ok to use a pair? in the quation the said "find a parametrization for intersection". can i answer with $(1,t,±t)$ ??

Comment: It would occur to me to check the meaning of "one sheet" hyperboloid.  Is it possible that instead of the "X" intersection there was some restriction that produces instead a "V" intersection?  In that case one might avoid the pair of lines and have instead something like $y=t,z=|t|$.  You will have to check the instructions.

Answer (score 0):

First parametrize the hyperboloid putting $$x = \cosh u \cos v, \quad y = \cosh u \sin v, \quad z = \sinh u $$Now force $x=1$, meaning $\cosh u \cos v = 1$. Write, say, $v = \arccos({\rm sech}\, u)$. Then one parametrization can by $$x = 1, \quad y = \cosh u \sin(\arccos({\rm sech}\, u)), \quad z = \sinh u.$$You can simplify that $y$ coordinate if you want, though.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer but do you know another way to do the parametrization? i mean without all of the "h" trigonometric functions.. we haven't learned that yet so i don't understand it and also i need to give the solution without these functions.
thank you.

Comment: Ok, you can write $x^2+y^2=1+z^2$ and put $x = \sqrt{1+z^2}\cos \theta$, $y = \sqrt{1+z^2} \sin \theta$. Then $x = 1$ gives $\theta = \arccos (1/\sqrt{1+ z^2})$ and $$x = 1, \quad y = \sqrt{1+z^2} \sin \arccos(1/\sqrt{1+z^2}), \quad z=z$$does the trick. Or use hardmath's suggestion in that comment.